# My google+ page is not an integer

Tags: api, console, google-plus

The google+ page of my association is now without an extension integer number, indeed its ID is +MyassociationOrg

So my question is, inside my console, into the API and ConsentScreen, what should I type inside "GOOGLE+ PAGE" fill? Google accept only integer number there.

Comment: I really don't understand why I got -1 for this question...I had explained everything carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the date/timestamp of a post by the Google+ page and "copy link address" (or similar feature) and paste the resulting URL `https://plus.google.com/116899029375914044550/posts/Qih4dvSWmBv` the ID is right after the .com.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Didn't know it. Thanks